# How to write to file (encode) modified camera frames in Windows Phone 8

Tags: opencv, windows-phone-8, libav

I have custom an camera app in Windows Phone 8. I need add a watermark image to each frame from camera capture and then record to a video.

I can customise each frame from the preview using the following code:

> int[] pixelData = new int[(int)(camera.PreviewResolution.Width *       camera.PreviewResolution.Height)];
>
> camera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(pixelData);
>
> return pixelData;

and write it back to the preview.

my problem is that while I can show the frames on the screen while the user is recording a movie using the camera I cant find a working solution for WP8 to encode the frames and audio to save to a file.

I already tried opencv,libav and others without success,
if anyone can point me to the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really don't want to do this, adding a watermark at runtime in managed code is a really bad idea. Even if you were to add it for every frame in the filestream sink, you still wouldn't be able to save to video to anywhere useful, as you don't have access to the MediaLibrary for video.

Comment: I would give the new Nokia Lumia Imaging API a shot. That thing has ridiculous libraries. Works on all windows phones.

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this.

```
private void GetCameraPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.CameraCaptureTask();
    cameraCaptureTask.Completed += cct_Completed;
    cameraCaptureTask.Show();
}

try
{
    if (e.TaskResult == Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.TaskResult.OK)
    {
        var imageStream = e.ChosenPhoto;
        var name = e.OriginalFileName;
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm"), Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0)), FontSize = 40 };
            BitmapImage finalImage = new BitmapImage();
            finalImage.SetSource(imageStream);
            WriteableBitmap wbFinal = new WriteableBitmap(finalImage);
            wbFinal.Render(tb, null);
            wbFinal.Invalidate();
            wbFinal.SaveJpeg(mem, wbFinal.PixelWidth, wbFinal.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            mem.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
            lib.SavePictureToCameraRoll("Copy" + name, mem.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exp) { MessageBox.Show(exp.Message); }
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: His question was for video, not audio. And 3rd party apps cannot write video to the MediaLibrary.